# How to do Full Text searching via Expression Tree in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, search, full-text-search, expression

I am Creating a e-commerce web Application which is using MVC code first approach.In this Application I have to apply search on Millions of Products and this search should be efficient on Performance basis.
I have wasted my 2 days in R and D in this thing.My search Requirement is something like below:-
Suppose if a user search 3 word letter e.g Hot Cup Design. Then the result should be :-

1)Fetch all the Product which has whole word i.e Hot Cup Design.(These Product should appear in the top of list)

2)Fetch all the Product which have splitted word also like Hot or Cup or Design.

I have studied on net and found that this task will accomplished with the help of Dynamic Expression Tree.But I have not use this ever.Please suggest what should i use for it and give an idea of similar code.
Any Response will be Appreciated.

Comment: While you could use LINQ for this and build up dynamic searches, a better option might be to use an engine that supports Full Text searching - either with a direct Full Text Index in SQL (if that's where your data is stored) or through something like Lucene, which is a dedicated search engine.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an introduction:
[Introduction](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/)